# SQL Server Compact Edition 4 : How to improve left outer join performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM Recipients AS R 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CampaignHistory AS H ON R.RecipientID = H.RecipientID
WHERE (H.RecipientID IS NULL)
```

Seems pretty standard, but I have 500k recipients....

The query takes about 8 minutes to execute, I'm looking for a way to improve this, any suggestions welcome.

EDIT Solution is:

Make sure you add index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_RecipientID ON CampaignHistory(RecipientID)
```

When VS throws an error , just click continue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an index on your join criteria (recipientid) and use `explain` to see the execution plan for further information about how the query is being executed.

Comment: how can I add the index?

Comment: Nevermind When - The CREATE INDEX SQL construct or statement is not supported. I just clicked continue...

Comment: Your suggestion brought the query down from 8 minutes to about 3 seconds... awesome....

Comment: Your documentation should have a section on `create index`. It is going to be something like `create index idx_name on campaignhistory (recipientid)`.

Comment: An example for those in need: CREATE INDEX IX_RecipientID ON CampaignHistory(RecipientID)